# Android SwitchPreference

Tags: android, preferences, switchpreference

How to make the SwitchPreferences look rectangular with yes and no texts.
I am short on time and so cannot create a custom lay out.
The one I am getting now is like this:- 'O-' '-O'.

Comment: that´s like: "Give me the code, I am too lazy to do it by myself".....

Answer (score 1):

Try this library:
https://github.com/BelkaLab/Android-Toggle-Switch
Or even this:
https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/android-material-design-tutorial/custom-switch-like-ios-in-android-tutorial/
But I would go with the first one.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately both talk about switches and i need something about switchpreferences.

Comment: I understand, sorry, I have no knowledge regarding SwitchPreference